# SonarQube Not Updating Report - "Line 5 is out of range for file Program.cs. File has 4 lines"

Tags: c#, .net-core, encoding, sonarqube, roslyn

I've created a .NET Core app with just 1 file - Program.cs

[image]

It simply prints from **1-100**

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("This is a sample exception");
    }
}
```

I've also setup SonarQube localy and ran my first scan using the command

```
dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="<TOKEN>"
```

It was success and I've got a report with CodeSmells (I'm conciously putting those to test SonarCube)

[image]

But once I corrected the code and re ran the command, I'm getting weard errors from sonar scanner. What can be the reason?

```
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line 5 is out of range for file Program.cs. File has 4 lines.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/:

> #### Build
>
> **Between the begin and end steps, you need to build your project, execute tests and generate code coverage data. This part is specific to your needs and it is not detailed here.**

So,

```cmd
dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="<TOKEN>"
```

is not enough, we have to:

```cmd
dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"project-key" /d:sonar.login="<token>"
dotnet build <path to solution.sln>
dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="<TOKEN>"
```

.